# How to fetch realtime tweets posted by particular twitter account / user?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Below code gives all tweets in array format for particular twitter account / user

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "your twitter account access_token",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "your twitter access_token_secret",
    'consumer_key' => "your twitter consumer_key",
    'consumer_secret' => "your twitter consumer_secret"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$requestMethod = 'GET';

$getfield = '?q=+from:test_account';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
    if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") { echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($string);
    echo "</pre>";.
```

But I want to do following 2 things.

1. Whenever I click / open any twitter account page on my website, it should give real time tweets for that twitter account. Means whenever new tweet(s) for that account are posted, they should be displayed immediately on my website.
2. Currently I need to generate oAuth data (access token, access token secret, consumer key, consumer secret) for each twitter account. So is there any way that I can fetch tweets of particular twitter account and display them on my website without generating above 4 mentioned values?

   Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to make new app for your user.
Second, the url you are using is just to access you timeline so that you can retrieve tweets from your account. Only for searching from user's tweets, you will need their screen name like @name.

try this,

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=from:test_account';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$tweet =  $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                 ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->performRequest();
$tweets = json_decode($tweet,1);
```

As suggested in documents, here
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks, I will make changes.